# Background UI Design Challenge

Tags: flutter, background, ui-design

How to create this app background design?? that blue background..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ther is a package called wave:

[image]

this is the link:

[wave 0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/wave)

Answer (score 2):

https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/08/flutter-draw-custom-shaps-clip-path.html?m=1 check this out example no. 4
it's always better write own code than using plugins

Comment: can you please create something like photo for  and upload the code???

Comment: i mean that blue wave background